# Outerjoin with a table of foreign keys in EF Data-first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table Users which contain user information. I have a table Products which contain product information. I have a table called UserProduct which acts as a junction table and whose fields are UserId and ProductId. I am using a Entity Framework database first approach.

I want to outerjoin using Linq to find the following data.

1. All Users in the Users table.
2. All Users who have bought a particular product in terms of a Boolean called isPurchased.

My thinking was to left outer join table User with UserProduct and get all users and whether they have a product something like this.

```
var result = from a in Users 
         join b in UserProduct(Not available through EF) on a.Id equals b.prodId into group1
         from g1 in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new 
         {
              id =  g1.Id,                  
              isPurchased = g1.prodId != null
         }.ToList();
```

However in EF mapping, the object UserProduct is not created and so I cannot use it directly in my Linq query? So how do I go about this? Is there a way I can use linq to join tables with the actual table name(UserProduct) instead of joining entities?

Comment: I think we may need more info about the names of your models and your tables.  For example, I would guess that `UserProduct` is a type, not a collection, which may be why your join doesn't make sense.

Comment: You need to go to your edmx file if you are doing database first. (sounds like you are).  Ensure that the object for UserProduct exists there.  If it does move on, if not right click design surface and add it from the database.  If it exists and is not showing it should be under your *.tt file under edmx file and just select 'Run Custom Tool' by right clicking the proper tt file and it should generate the POCO for you.

Comment: @djangojazz There is no object for UserProduct in the edmx because it's a table of only foreign keys and so there will not be an object for it.

Comment: ???  You are asking how you get something and then that you don't need it.  You cannot get something from Entity Framework that doesn't exist there as a generated POCO to my knowledge.  That is how Entity Framework works, those are the entities.  They usually exist as DbSet<(name)> and then a generated POCO with the properties to play with that correlate to the table it is generated for.

Comment: If you have a junction table, you should have `List` properties in the `Users` and `Products` objects that represent the junction table information - can you post your definitions for `Users` and `Products`? Also your sample code doesn't test for a particular product?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Users` contains a property `List<Products> products` to represent the junction information, and a variable `boughtProductId` to represent the particular product:

```
var result = from u in Users
             let isPurchased = u.products.Any(p => p.Id == boughtProductId)
             select new {
                 id =  isPurchased ? boughtProductId : null,
                 isPurchased
             }.ToList();
```